# How to Connect FCoE card to existing FC SAN

Tags: storage, ethernet, san

I have an existing Fibre Channel SAN and existing Ethernet Network. The SAN consists of FC Disk Storage an FC switch and a couple Hosts connected to the Switch via the FC cards in them. The Ethernet net work is all connected via a Gigabit switch.

I would like to Utilize a FCoE compatible card in another host however i do no know how to connect this card to gain access to my IP Ethernet infrastructure and also the FC SAN infrastructure.

Do i need a FCoE to FC gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need an FCoE-capable switch. You may also need to upgrade your Ethernet switches.  What brand and model is your existing FC switch?   Also, FCoE does not run over IP, it runs over Ethernet only and is not routable.

Comment: Hi David,thanks for the answer. the existing FC switch is just a Brocade 200E (4Gb) so no support for FCoE there. its part of an existing infrastructure. FCoE Host and Storage are all on the same site so dont need routing. Could you suggest an entry level FCoE switch? thanks!

Comment: The 200E is definitely not FCoE capable.  If you want to stay with Brocade, you want one of the Brocade VDX switches.  I would talk to your  switch vendor about your specific requirements.